# Get difference between two collections with different keys

Tags: php, laravel

I have two collections to compare:

```php
$collection1 = collect([
    'alex',
    'john'
]);
```

```php
$collection2 = collect([
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'alex',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'john',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'joe',
    ],
]);
```

I want to compare `collection2` with `$collection1` and only get items which the `name` value doesnt in the  other collection, the result i want:

```
[
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'joe',
]
```

But the problem is the first collection have flat array so, i did this:

```php
$collection2->diffUsing($collection1, function ($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b);
});
```

But i get the error :

> ErrorException : strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: have you tried `whereNotIn` yet? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenotin

Comment: use `array_diff` function..

Comment: Doing `$arr = array_column($array2, 'name')` will create an array of just the names from the 2nd array, then you can just compare them directly

Comment: use like this ..`array_diff($array1, $array2)`  [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)..

Comment: @lagbox thanks man it worked, feel free to add a reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereNotIn` to do this, passing the first collection as the values you want to filter out:

```
$result = $collect2->whereNotIn('name', $collect1);
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherenotin)